# Timers in Windows

Tags: windows, delphi, timer

I'm experiencing [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050189) with the SetTimer API.

Just for curiosity, what are my others options in Delphi?

- There's [Multimedia Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- `TTimer` but it's just a wrapper around SetTimer / KillTimer

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1236/Timers-Tutorial#QueueTimers  All are described here.  I am a bit hesitant to use Multimedia Timers, but they still perform well under Windows 8.  Either way, the Queue Timers, or Multimedia Timers, are going to give much better results.

Comment: Post this as answer please :)

Comment: You can look at the [TJvThreadTimer](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvThreadTimer). A high resolution timer which operates on an internal thread instead of relying on the windows api. Can be used without a windows handle.

Comment: There are also waitable timers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[codeproject.com/Articles/1236/Timers-Tutorial#QueueTimers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1236/Timers-Tutorial#QueueTimers) All are described here. I am a bit hesitant to use Multimedia Timers, but they still perform well under Windows 8. Either way, the Queue Timers, or Multimedia Timers, are going to give much better results.

Answer (score 3):

When you need to do work according to a certain timing, you should also be asking if you need to do the work in threads. There's a big difference between handling timer events and *off-loading* work from the main thread into separate threads, both in how to set this up and in how it will perform (considering more and more hardware has multi-core processors).

The most basic way to do this is inherit from TThread, but it's not that straight-forward. (See 'Thread' in the Project New dialog, or [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TThread)) There are also a number of [threading platforms for Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbthread/tp/threading-libraries-for-Delphi.htm).

Answer (score 3):

I've written [queue timer wrapper as a Delphi component](http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/a-better-timer-for-a-delphi-programmer/)
The project is discontinued but you can take `TksTimer` code or install `ksTools` package.